# Ро-алгоритм Полларда

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Значит, пишу алгоритм Полларда:

```
Пусть надо разложить на множители число P
Шаг 1. Выбирается многочлен f(x) с целочисленными коэффициентами, степени не выше 2. Обычно берется многочлен вида y = x2 + c(mod P).
Шаг 2. Случайно выбирается x0 = y0 меньше P.
Шаг 3. Вычисляются значения xi = f(xi − 1)(modP),yi = f(f(yi − 1))(modP).
Шаг 4. Находится d = ( | xi − yi | ,P).
Шаг 5. Если d = 1, происходит переход на шаг 3, если d = P, происходит остановка - факторизацию провести не удалось. Если 1 < d < P, то найдено разложение числа P.
```

Теперь пытаюсь реализовать на питоне, бесконечно висит. Прикрепляю код сюда:

```
from random import randint
from fractions import gcd
def f(x, N):
  return (x**2 - 1) // N
N = int(input())
global i
i = 0
global x0
x0 = randint(10,N-1)
def fun(N):
  y0 = x0
  arr = [x0]
  a = [y0]
  i += 1
  arr[i] = f(arr[i-1], N) // N
  a[i] = f(f(a[i-1], N), N) // N
  d = gcd(abs(arr[i]-a[i]), N)
  if d == 1:
    return fun(N)
  elif d == N:
    return 'факторизация не удалась'
  else:
    return d
print(fun(N))
```

Помогите найти ошибку. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Что такое `x2` на первом шаге? Или это квадрат?

Comment: @VTT да, это возведение в квадрат

Answer (score 2):

Операция mod - остаток от деления, значит нужно использовать не //, а %